# Redirect nginx port 80 to http2 443 fails

Tags: nginx, https, http, ipv6, http2

Searched tons of links on the web, I don't get why this conf doesn't redirect properly from http://example.com to https://example.com

My [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) conf:

```
# HTTPS
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    index index.html;

    # Prevent nginx HTTP Server Detection
    server_tokens off;

    server_name example.org;
    root /home/www/example.org;

    # Let's Encrypt conf
    include /etc/nginx/ssl.conf;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.org.access.log;
}

# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.org;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    }
}
```

netstat:

```
# netstat -nptl | grep :80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      71768/nginx: master 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      71768/nginx: master
```

What I'm doing wrong?

When I try `curl`, I get:

```
$ curl -Lv http://example.org
*   Trying 123:123:123:123:80...
* Connected to example.org (123:123:123:123) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed
* Closing connection 0
curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed
```

And a `telnet`:

```
$ telnet example.org 80
Trying 123:123:123:123...
Connected to example.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Let'sEncrypt file

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0001/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0001/privkey.pem;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/private/dh2048.pem;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000";
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
```

No issue with SSL vhost.

Comment: Possibly you have one or more additional server blocks you haven't disclosed and that the problem could  be in there. Please edit your question to include the output of `nginx -T`  - an example of a similar issue  where the problem was related to a  'spdy' or 'http2' directives in a different server entry on port 80 https://serverfault.com/q/1041653/37681

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.org;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    }
}
```

with

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name example.org;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Same error with `curl` and https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ said it's down on http

Comment: The 80 port is reachable as client side

Comment: my letsencrypt conf has 3 lines `ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem;
include snippets/ssl-params.conf;` ... are you sure, you're including everything ?

Comment: The 443 `vhost` works as a charm. The 80 one, have no `ssl` conf

Comment: Added LetsEncrypt file in my original POST

Comment: Issue find, see duplicated, plused+